# Nested object on Listview seems to get garbage collected, not getting notified of changed properties

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a list of AttendanceClass POCO object available from my ViewModel:

```
private List<AttendanceClass> _Classes;
public List<AttendanceClass> Classes
{
    get { return _Classes; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _Classes, value); }
}
```

The AttendanceClass object has nested objects:

```
public class AttendanceClass : RealmObject
{
    public IList<AttendanceStudent> Students { get; }
}

public partial class AttendanceStudent : RealmObject
{
    public int CheckOffReasonID { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="AttendanceListView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" 
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            SeparatorColor="LightGray"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
                                <Label FontSize="7" Text="{Binding Students[0].CheckOffReasonID}"></Label>
                                <Button Text="Toggle" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TogglePresentCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=AttendanceListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></Button>                                    
                            </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

You see, I reference the first item in the Students list. The expected result is when tabbing the Button, the Label gets updated with another value. 
On Android this seems to work for a while, but suddenly stops reacting on the button. In the console output I often see a "garbage collecting" message when the error starts kicking in. So I suppose it, somehow gets GC'ed.
On iPhone it does not react at all to the button tab.

When button is tabbed, it runs this code, that saves using Realm, in which I also expects realm object to notify UI:

```
private void TogglePresent(AttendanceClass attClass)
    {
        var student = attClass.Students[0];
        try
        {
            RealmHelper.Database.Write(() =>
            {
                student.CheckOffReasonID = student.CheckOffReasonID == PresentId ? 0 : PresentId;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{e.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that getting rid of Realm, was the solution.
I removed the dependency for RealmObject on model classes and handled the property notification myself. That removed the bug.

I cannot recommend Realm. Too much magic happening in its engine, without having control of it as a developer. Also it it too restrictive on types on model classes and how you interact with them.

I now go for Sqlite for handling the offline experience.